# How to pick the right Ubuntu version for ASrock Rack C2750D4I

Tags: 12.04, server, system-installation, 12.10

could you tell me what is the best option for Ubuntu to install on [AsRock Rack C2750D4I](http://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=C2750D4I#Specifications), as they say in the speck 12.04/12.10 x64 Bit, I've already run to the following conclusions:

It must be 64 bit. ( amd64 ) I've got 8 GB of Ram DDR3 1600
It must be a "server" version with open-box as a GUI

The dilemmas:

1.Does the 32 bit software run on 64 bit Ubuntu as compared to Windows?

2.As the speck says 12.04/12.10 (x64) and the Ubuntu site says (14.04.3)
  Which 64 bit ( amd64 ) Ubuntu is the best for my machine:

12.04    Network installer:
  12.04.5  Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server (64-bit) Via torrent file
  12.10    Available only for ARM based processors (mine is not ARM):
  14.04.3  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server (64-bit): Found on the download page:
  15.10    Ubuntu Server 15.10: Also on the download page:

Though I will indeed skip the PAE because:
 1. My board can run Ubuntu x64
 2. It is also quite new
 3. PAE will slow it down compared to the native 32 bit OS
 4. [C2750](http://ark.intel.com/products/77987/Intel-Atom-Processor-C2750-4M-Cache-2_40-GHz) is a native 64 bit CPU with PAE supported

Tell me guys what do you think ...

This is not about picking the best light-weight version of Ubuntu, but instead the one with more support !!!

Comment: It's not duplicate, Because I am asking a totally different concept. My goal is not minimalist installation. I've got 8 cores x 2.4GHz. I am aiming for system compatibility for the Ubuntu application with my hardware.

Comment: Sounds like a fair choice, I will try. As long it supports 32 bit programs. There is a chance, that I will not be able to run my old 32 bit most needed applications like the mount manager for example and [Valve] Steam ( Half-life 2, Garry's mod servers ). The biggest dilemma are the 3-rd party applications, but once I got it set-up I will beck it up it to rid of any unnecessary host downs. So far I think it could work, as I managed to run on it Ubuntu 10.04 ( Desktop )

Comment: Neat ! nothing to worry about ;) Have to try this one out Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ( Desktop ).

It turns out that the CPU can handle it with no problems and it runs quite fast even with the GUI enabled via x11vnc on gigabit lan.